# Why aren't OCSP error messages signed?

Tags: security, certificate, rfc, ca, ocsp

I'm trying to understand OCSP. I almost read the entire RFC but I'm not understanding why error message are not signed. The issues are obviously: If an error message isn't signed, a MiTM can simply deny the services replying client's requests with errors like unauthorized, internalError [...]

From RFC I can read:

> In case of errors, the OCSP responder may return an error message.
>   These messages are not signed.

without understanding why.
Wouldn't be most secure with a sign? Maybe I'm missing the point there, but I think that it would be really more secure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OCSP client is interested in verifying a certificate revocation status. The message that returns the status is signed to avoid a rogue OCSP server to return fake response (e.g. return status "good" when it actual status is "revoked").

When OCSP server indicates an error that the revocation status of the certificate is undefined. The OCSP client should consider on rejecting such certificate or trying to verify it via CRL or another OCSP server. Optionally this can be configurable on OCSP client to let the administrator decide. The same is related to the signed OCSP response that carries status "unknown".